# Oulook 2003: filter emails based on a calculated field

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, email-filter

InOutlook 2003 I would like to move emails where the time difference between fields **modified** and **received** is greater than a fixed amount of time.

I can easily create a [calculated field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203813%28v=office.11%29.aspx), but cannot order by it (outlook limitation), so the emails are scattered and it is tedious and error prone to select only those which meet the criteria.

I tried to create a filter too using the [sql DASL syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewdelin/archive/2005/05/11/416312.aspx), but it seems to me it doesn't support comaprison between fields, so it is inapplicable.

I checked if I could create a rule, but the **modified** is not supported there and **received** wants a static condition.

Is there a way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

No way without using VBA, sorry. In "run a script" rule you can check all required conditions and move emails if needed.